# Creating a CAPS button on Tcl Tk

Tags: button, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am needed to create a window with an input line and a single button that will work like this:

The button is going to be labeled "CAPS" and when it is pressed, the text on the input line will turn to Uppercase characters. At the same time with button label will become "small" and when it is pressed again all characters in the input line are gonna become lowercase characters and the button will again be labeled "CAPS" resetting it's function.

Comment: That sounds like a terrific idea. Are you having trouble making it work? Please describe the problem and we will try to help you resolve it.

Comment: Sure. Show us what you've tried and I'm sure we can help. One key insight in this situation is to remember that you can change the text of a button using "configure" as part of the callback that is executed when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

If the "algorithm" is very basic, the greatest difficulty i met with tcl is this syntax which seems a little bit strange:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

pack [entry .e]
pack [button .b -text "Uppercase" -command "ToggleCase"]

proc ToggleCase {} {
    set temp [.e get]
    .e delete 0 end
    if {[.b cget -text] eq "Uppercase"} {
        .e insert 0 [string toupper $temp]
        .b configure -text "Lowercase"
    } else {
        .e insert 0 [string tolower $temp]
        .b configure -text "Uppercase"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code was correct in principle, but I'm curious as to what was the problem _in your eyes_ with Tcl syntax?

Comment: FWIW, it's possible to do better by (ab)using the validation mechanism — enforcing changes at the keystroke level — but it's a lot of work to get right. (I tried writing an answer based on this, but it was too long, complicated and hard for someone else to use.)